# Limpar objeto não utilizado da memoria

Tags: java, memory-leaks

Tenho um set que contém milhões de Strings e usa muita memória, o problema é que depois que eu utilizo ele dentro de um foreach a memória utilizada não é liberada, tendo como resultado após algumas execuções do método um `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`. Como posso liberar a memória desse objeto? Já tentei atribuir ele como null e rodar `Runtime.getRuntime().gc;`, porém não está liberando a memória.

```
public void saveAllData(Set<String> logSet, RegexEnum regexEnum) {
        Pattern dataPattern = Pattern.compile(regexEnum.getRegexPattern()[0]);
        Pattern urlPattern = Pattern.compile(regexEnum.getRegexPattern()[1]);

        Set<Log> logsToBeSaved = new HashSet<>();
        for (String log : logSet) {
            String data = getContentInLogLine(dataPattern, log, regexEnum.getGroupPattern()[0]);
            String url = getContentInLogLine(urlPattern, log, regexEnum.getGroupPattern()[1]);
            if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(data) && !StringUtils.isEmpty(url)) {
                if (url.contains("?")) {
                    url = url.substring(0, url.indexOf("?"));
                }

                logsToBeSaved.add(new Log(data, "/".concat(url), regexEnum));
            }
        }
        this.iLogRepository.saveAll(logsToBeSaved);
        LOGGER.info("Cleaning log objects.");
        logSet = null;
        logsToBeSaved = null;
        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente chamar o método clear() do seu Set, Ficaria algo como :

```
public void saveAllData(Set<String> logSet, RegexEnum regexEnum) {
    Pattern dataPattern = Pattern.compile(regexEnum.getRegexPattern()[0]);
    Pattern urlPattern = Pattern.compile(regexEnum.getRegexPattern()[1]);

    Set<Log> logsToBeSaved = new HashSet<>();
    for (String log : logSet) {
        String data = getContentInLogLine(dataPattern, log, regexEnum.getGroupPattern()[0]);
        String url = getContentInLogLine(urlPattern, log, regexEnum.getGroupPattern()[1]);
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(data) && !StringUtils.isEmpty(url)) {
            if (url.contains("?")) {
                url = url.substring(0, url.indexOf("?"));
            }

            logsToBeSaved.add(new Log(data, "/".concat(url), regexEnum));
        }
    }
    this.iLogRepository.saveAll(logsToBeSaved);
    LOGGER.info("Cleaning log objects.");
    logSet.clear(); //Codigo implementado aqui
}
```

Comment: O método clear do Set chama o método clear do HashMap interno, que atribui null a cada elemento do map, não seria o mesmo que já estou fazendo? Mesmo assim testei e sem sucesso. Tentei usar um new HashSet<>(), sem sucesso também.